# How to make BlockingQueue to accept multiple types?

Tags: java, generics, blockingqueue

I have class `X`, class `Y` and class `Z`. If `X` or `Y` perform specific conditions, they should be put into `BlockingQueue`. Class `Z` just takes them from the queue.

I know that creating something like this:

```
BlockingQueue<X,Y> BQueue=new ArrayBlockingQueue<X,Y>(length);
```

is illegal. How to make it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to allow the `BlockingQueue` accept any object type:

```
BlockingQueue<Object> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(length);
```

then, on `take()` operation, you just look of what particular class the object is:

```
Object o = q.take();
if (o instanceof X) {
    X x = (X) o;
    // do work with x
} else if (o instanceof Y) {
    Y y = (Y) o;
    // do work with y
} else {
    // o is neither X nor Y
}
```

If `X` and `Y` are inherited from common class or implement common interface, make your queue more specific:

```
BlockingQueue<XYInterface> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(length);
```

Comment: `if (o instanceof X)` is pretty ugly.

Comment: @PatrickCollins if `X` is not subclass of `Y` or vice versa, it will work fine. Otherwise, queue of the most general type (X or Y) should be created.

Comment: IMO this question suggests a design flaw on @prgst's part --- s/he needs to re-think his/her class hierarchy and ask if this makes sense --- it probably doesn't.

Comment: @PatrickCollins sometimes it is not easy or even possible. Suppose you have messages of different types from different sources and need to consume them by one consumer only. You cannot make them implement common interface and declare strategy, and wrapping them in wrapping class also won't help: on unwrapping you also will be required to discover particular type in some way.

Comment: Use the Command Pattern, have the objects carry around their own processing behavior. Or, give them an `addConsumer` method that gives them a reference to the consumer, and then a `consume` method that calls the appropriate method on the consumer you just added. There is never a good reason to do this.

Comment: @PatrickCollins what you describe is good design, for sure. But sometimes you cannot change declaration of classes that you have to work with (they are final or are located in jars used by another parts of enterprise)

Comment: I believe this solution is quite fine for me. Thank You :)

Comment: Could You tell me how to assign `X` to the queue? When I am in `X` class I try to put it on queue using `queue.put(this)` however it is not working.

Comment: No error is displayed. `X` `Y` `Z` are implementing runnable. While `X` is on queue it is said to `wait()` and so it does. But when `Z` takes it, `X` do not stop waiting, even though it is said to not to do it anymore.

Comment: @prgst I think this is another question not related to this one. You may post another question where you put code snippets to help members understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what Sasha proposes and use a `BlockingQueue<Object>` but I prefer to declare common functionality into an interface and then make each class handle it's own functionality instead of using `instanceof` declarations:

```
public interface Common {

    boolean shouldEnqueue();

    void doSomething();

}

public class X implements Common {

    public boolean shouldEnqueue() {
        ...
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is X");
    }
}

public class Y implements Common {

    public boolean shouldEnqueue() {
        ...
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("This is Y");
    }
}

public class Producer {

    private final BlockingQueue<Common> queue;

    void maybeEnqueue(Common c) {
        if(c.shouldEnqueue()) {
            queue.add(c);
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer {
    private final BlockingQueue<Common> queue;

    void doSomething() {
        queue.take().doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes of course, circumstances will have an impact on the solution. When possible this is the one I prefer though.